# Does the Hindered status effect affect only walking speed or over all speed?

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds-3e

Does the Hindered status effect affect only walking speed or over all speed?

Meaning is flight, tunneling, swimming effected and reduced Rank -1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text of the entry does not seem to limit its effect to walking speed.

> A hindered character moves at half normal speed (–1 speed rank). Immobile supersedes hindered.

So yes, it would still apply if running (In this case, a successful Athletics check would give you +1, which would cancel out the Hindered and let you move at normal speed) or using other forms of transportation (other than Teleport, which does not have a speed).

Comment: This is a case where Descriptors can matter. If the source of Hindered shouldn't affect the movement mode - such as a "high winds" Environment and Burrowing - then it shouldn't matter. Though that failure may qualify as a Complication and be worth a Hero Point.